# Interactive bash in Docker under mingw on Windows

Tags: linux, bash, windows, docker, mingw

I'm using a bash shell (Mingwg64) on windows, to run bash from a docker container.

```
Tobi@DESKTOP MINGW64 /
$ docker run -i debian bash
ls
```

gives the result: `bash: line 1: $'ls\r': command not found` which from what I can tell is because there's a `\r` prepended to the usual `\n` when I press the enter key - as I'm on windows.

Anyone know a good fix for this?

Comment: @GAD3R No, it does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) tells:

> If you do not specify `-a` then Docker will attach to both stdout and
> stderr . You can specify to which of the three standard streams
> (`STDIN`, `STDOUT`, `STDERR`) you’d like to connect instead, as in:
>
> ```
> $ docker run -a stdin -a stdout -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
> ```
>
> **For interactive processes (like a shell), you must use `-i` `-t` together
> in order to allocate a tty for the container process**. `-i` `-t` is often
> written `-it` as you’ll see in later examples. Specifying `-t` is
> forbidden when the client is receiving its standard input from a pipe
> [...]

So you should use `-it` instead of `-i`: the *tty* layer will have a chance to translate the terminal input from `\r\n` into `\n` for the target system:

```
$ docker run -it debian bash
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer